# Update timestamp fields with now() incrementally

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table

```
id timestamp
1  2021-02-07 04:14:00
2  2021-02-07 04:14:00
3  2021-02-07 04:14:00
```

How can I update time stamp with now() + 1 sec?
Expected result:

```
id timestamp
1  2021-08-17 04:14:00
2  2021-08-17 04:14:02
3  2021-08-17 04:14:03
```

Next query just set the same time for all records:

```
UPDATE some_table
      SET event_timestamp = now()
```

Comment: If the answer provided solved your problem please accept it. Accepting an answer helps later questioners having the same issue. Further it removes the question from the unanswered queue. If  not sufficient to solve your issue please post what remains.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`.

```
update t
    set timestamp = now() + (seqnum - 1) * interval '1 second'
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by timestamp order by id) as seqnum
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.id = t.id ;
```

If the `id` is really sequential, you can use:

```
update t
    set timestamp = now() + (id - 1) * interval '1 second';
```